# Variables in .animate() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, firefox, animation

quick question. I'm using the below .animate() code with a variable:

```
context.prevAll().animate({'top' : aVariable}, 100, 'linear');
```

This works just fine in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox. Now, If I replace the 'aVariable' with an actual value, like '200px', it works just fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

I should have probably spent more time Googling this, but does anyone know why this behavior is occurring?

Think I'm just gonna start rolling Greensock for all animations period...

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: I use variables in `animate()` for years ago and I haven't that problem never (not in firefox nor chrome nor IE). Share a working example. You can use stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net